# Get name of DAC

Tags: linux

I bought second hand a streamer under Linux with a Sabre DAC. The manual say it is a ES9028. Further down is says ES9038. There are some differences between the two DAC. How can I get the name of the DAC which is inside?

I tried:

```
$aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: DAC [ES90x8Q2M DAC], device 0: ES90x8Q2M DAC es90x8q2m-dac-dai-0 []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: OnBoard [USB Audio OnBoard], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: OnBoard [USB Audio OnBoard], device 1: USB Audio [USB Audio #1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: OnBoard [USB Audio OnBoard], device 2: USB Audio [USB Audio #2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

The driver doesn't distinuish between ES9028 and ES9038. I tried also:

```
$ /sbin/lsmod | grep snd
snd_usb_audio         126976  0
snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_usb_audio
snd_usbmidi_lib        24576  1 snd_usb_audio
snd_rawmidi            24576  1 snd_usbmidi_lib
```

and

```
$ /sbin/lsmod | grep snd
snd_usb_audio         126976  0
snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_usb_audio
snd_usbmidi_lib        24576  1 snd_usb_audio
snd_rawmidi            24576  1 snd_usbmidi_lib
```

I there a better way?

Comment: You can open it up and look at the chip.

Comment: I guess that's the only solution. I've tried so many things now, like lshw, inxi and so on. But it seems that they just print out the drivers name.